# macbook pro with windows 10 partition-unable to start windows because too little disk space

Tags: windows-10, macbook-pro, disk-space, windows-installation

macbook pro with windows 10 partition-unable to start windows because too little disk space--just hangs..  When I plug in the windows boot thumb drive, do a restart from the mac side, I see the bootable windows and am able to initiate its loading. The next screen: language selection screen pops up, but I do not have even see the cursor to make selections and thus no way to proceed to get to the C: drive and start removing files. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to mount the Boot Camp partition from the Mac side [through Disk Utility or any specialist NTFS utility] - though NTFS is mounted read-only by default.

The best tool I know of for mounting NTFS read/write is [Paragon NTFS for Mac](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/). This comes with a free trial, but I don't know what functionality may be enabled in the trial [as I already own it, so it's hard to check].

Answer (score -2):

If you don't have enough disk space, you **will not be able to install Windows 10 in any way**. Windows 10 is a really heavy OS. The issue that you're having with your mouse is because Windows doesn't come with the touchpad drivers for Apple computers. You should consider turning off your laptop and normally boot to Windows 10.